# How to hide "null='true'" in JAXB xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am producing an xml file via JAXB which results in elements that look like this:

```
<someData null="true"/>
```

Here is what the Java class looks like:

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"someData"})
public class someClass implements Serializable {
    private String someData;

    public String getSomeData() {
        return someData;
    }

    public void setSomeData(String someData) {
        this.someData = someData;
    }
}
```

Is there an annotation, or some other mechanism, that will produce an output that removes someData from the xml if it is nil, or produces an empty element like this?:

```
<someData/>
```

Comment: Not including null elements is a default behavior. Annotations look OK. Could you please post your code fragment that shows  how are you calling JAXB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your object model the following demo code:

```
package forum10437439;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(someClass.class);

        someClass someClass = new someClass();
        someClass.setSomeData(null);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        JAXBElement<someClass> je = new JAXBElement<someClass>(new QName("root"), someClass.class, someClass); 
        marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
    }

}
```

Will produce the XML result that you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root/>
```

**Possible Cause**

Have you registered an `XmlAdapter` at the package level that may be converting instances of `String` to the representation you are seeing?